# Android FileObserver strange behavior on marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fileobserver

I am using FileObserver to update a recyclerview listing files inside a fragment using runOnUiThread. I have noticed something really interesting. Whenever I launch my app and onEvent is called in the top directory of the internal storage the recyclerview doesn't update but when I reset or update fragment with some other actions the ui starts updating. The interesting thing is that onEvent is fired, I have checked with a toast, just the UI doesn't update. I worked on it for 2-3 hours thinking that the problem was with my app but then I tried with 2, 3 file managers and noticed the same behavior. What is going on?